# Program breaks when trying to add string to structure

Tags: c++, string, data-structures

I just started to learn c++. I got problem with structure. When I am adding data to structure program beaks when it tries to add string to structure. I really don't know where is problem. here is my code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using  namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    typedef struct hardware
{
    int id; // will store information
    string name;
    int year;
    float price;
    hardware *next; // the reference to the next hardware
};

    hardware *head = NULL;  //empty linked list
    int tempid = 0,tempyear=0, hardware_number = 0,  counter = 0;
    string tempname="";
float tempprice=0;
cout<<"Unesite sifru proizvoda:";
cin>>tempid;                        
cout<<"Unesite naziv proizvoda:";
cin>>tempname;  
cout<<"Unesite godinu proizvoda:";
cin>>tempyear;  
cout<<"Unesite cijenu proizvoda:";
cin>>tempprice;
cout<<"Unijeli ste : ID: "<<tempid<<", naziv: "<<tempname<<", godina: "<<tempyear<<", cijena: "<<tempprice<<",  hardware No: "

<<++counter;
hardware *temp;                         
temp = (hardware*)malloc(sizeof(hardware)); 
temp->id = tempid;  
temp->name = tempname;              
temp->year = tempyear;
temp->price = tempprice;
temp->next = head;                  
head = temp;
return 0;
```

EDIT 1:
When I run program it compiles fine. After I enter data that will fill structure (id, name, price, year, ...) program breaks on this line

```
temp->name = tempname;
```

Here is error output:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in proba.exe

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Comment: You don't describe the problem. Does "breaks" mean it doesn't compile, doesn't link, crashes, gives incorrect output, or what? Also what code do you think does this "adding data to structure" that caused your code to break?

Comment: Please show the errors. Don't use malloc in c++ (use `new`, and smart pointers). 'stdafx' is for windows programs and isn't standard.

Comment: Added error output and showed where program breaks. It compiles but when it reach state when it's adding string to structure it breaks.

Comment: you don't need to typedef a struct name in c++, it's automatic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `temp = new hardware;` instead of `temp = (hardware*)malloc(sizeof(hardware));` to ensure the constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

`temp->name` is never constructed, so you can't use it on the left side of an assignment operator. If you think you did construct it, please point to the line of code that you think constructs it. I'll bet you can't. (You allocated memory for it, but you never constructed a string in that memory!)

Comment: It was in code. I think that I accidentally delete it when I was adding code. I edited my post and added that line. Sorry for that. Really my bad.

Comment: @ZhiZha Where is that line? I still don't see it. Your bug is that you never construct `temp->name`. You try to assign it a value even though it was never constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Use new() and not malloc() for construct your classes.
In this case the constructor for your std::string is never called !

If you are beginner in C++ I suggest you to always use new/delete for the moment, and not malloc/free.